# Using dplyr to select rows containing non-missing values in several specified columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is my data

```
data <- data.frame(a= c(1, NA, 3), b = c(2, 4, NA), c=c(NA, 1, 2))
```

I wish to select only the rows with no missing data in colunm a AND b. For my example, only the first row will be selected.

I could use

```
data %>% filter(!is.na(a) & !is.na(b))
```

to achieve my purpose. But I wish to do it using if_any/if_all, if possible. I tried `data %>% filter(if_all(c(a, b), !is.na))` but this returns an error. My question is how to do it in dplyr through if_any/if_all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data %>% 
  filter(if_all(c(a,b), ~!is.na(.)))

  a b  c
1 1 2 NA
```

Comment: Great solution. I wish to learn why the tilde sign and why the dot inside is.na()?

Answer (score 1):

This could do the trick - use `filter_at` and `all_vars` in `dplyr`:

```
data %>% 
   filter_at(vars(a, b), all_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

Output:

```
#  a b  c
#1 1 2 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `filter` with `if_all`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   filter(if_all(c(a,b), complete.cases))
```

-output

```
  a b  c
1 1 2 NA
```